Health connect permissions Androi 11
I am not able to start health connect permissions on Android 11. I am always getting  Toast.makeText(this, "onPermissionsDenied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show().
 private val permissions = setOf(
    HealthPermission.getWritePermission(BloodPressureRecord::class),
    HealthPermission.getWritePermission(HeartRateRecord::class),
).map { it }.toTypedArray()


private val permissions2 = setOf(
    HealthPermission.getWritePermission(BloodPressureRecord::class),
    HealthPermission.getWritePermission(HeartRateRecord::class),
)

val requestPermissionActivityContract = PermissionController.createRequestPermissionResultContract()

val requestPermissions = registerForActivityResult(requestPermissionActivityContract) { granted ->
    if (granted.containsAll(permissions.toSet())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "All permissions granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onPermissionsDenied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

suspend fun checkPermissionsAndRun(healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient) {
    val granted = healthConnectClient.permissionController.getGrantedPermissions()
    if (granted.containsAll(permissions.toSet())) {
        // Permissions already granted; proceed with inserting or reading data
    } else {
        requestPermissions.launch(permissions2)
    }
}

